# Dynamically add <img> elements to canvas

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I'm trying to make a react app.  I have a div element with a bunch of images that's added dynamically.  After clicking a button I want to add each image to the canvas.  I'm having trouble adding it to the canvas because it keeps giving me an error because I'm not loading the images before using drawImage().  I'm confused how this works because the image is on the DOM already, but I have to preload it or something?

This is what I have right now, which doesn't give me an error but doesn't do what I want it to because I was experimenting.  At first I just had a for loop to get the src of every , but that threw an error and I though I needed an object.  So I made an object literal and pushed the src of every  there and then to the canvas, but it gave the same error.  I just have an Image constructor to experiment with, but I don't know what to do with it.

```
captureImage(){
        let canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas")
        let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d")
        let imgDiv = document.querySelector(".images")
        let imgEl = document.getElementsByTagName("img")
        let imgObj = new Image
        imgObj.onload = function(){
            ctx.drawImage(imgObj.images[n],0,0)
        }
        if (imgEl){
            for (var n = 0;n < imgEl.length;n++){
                imgObj[n] = imgEl[n].src
                    console.log(imgObj.images)
            }
        }
    }
```

The function is called onClick.  I'm just really confused.  I don't really understand where to place things.

Comment: `imgObj = new Image` means that `imgObj` will be an HTMLImageElement. Though you try to access it like if it were an Array when you do `imgObj[n]` and like if it were a simple Object when you do `imgObj.images`.

Comment: That being said, if you are sure they're loaded, you could simply use the images in DOM directly : `if(imgEl){ for(var n=0; n<imgEl.length; n++){ ctx.drawImage(imgEl[n], x ,y);}}` and remove all these `imgObj`

Comment: @Kaiido Actually this worked perfectly.  I wish I had what I tried originally, because it was similar to what you had, but I was getting an error.  I guess I was confused on if my images were loaded or not and how to use the canvas.  Thank you.